# Can anyone help me make a script that rotates towards a specific angle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a unity game and
I have a gameobject i need to constantly rotate towards a target angle
And it needs to take the shortest way there

I have tried to use lerp co-routines to add/subbtract it to the angle but when i use it to quickly it gets stuck in weird positions

```
Transform target;


float speed;

//The angle to constantly rotate torwards
float yRotation = 120f;
private int dick;
void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        if (dick < 3)
        {
            dick += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dick = 1;
        }

    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (dick >0 )
        {
            dick -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dick = 3;
        }
    }
    if (dick == 1)
    {
        yRotation = 0;
    }
    else if (dick == 2)
    {
        yRotation = 120;
    }
    else if (dick == 3)
    {
        yRotation = 240;
    }
```

As you might see there is some parts from the old code

The reason i use this kind of gear system is so that it cant get stuck in weird positions but i am not sure how to constantly rotate it to that target angle

Comment: Sory for the variable names and i have tried     IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)
    {

        var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
        var toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
        for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
        {
            float oldtime = t;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
            yield return null  
        }
        if (fromAngle != toAngle) { rotable = false; }
        print(toAngle);
        if (fromAngle == toAngle) { rotable = true; }
    }

Comment: Looks like `if (dick>0) dick -=1` should actually be `if (dick>1) dick -=1`

Comment: Thank you but it is not that part i need help with,    i need help with the rotation itself

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try :

- In the Update, every time calculate the direction between you and the target, then calcultate the Angle, and then use Quaternion.AngleAxis() or simply Quaternion.RotateTowards()
- You can also simply use Transform.LookAt(yourTarger.transform)